# Split text file to only return numbers

Tags: python, text

The contents of the text file is something like:

`A customer has purchased your 33%-off item for 2,999 dollars`

I want to only return the 2999 and nothing else and I tried the following, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
def read_file():
    file = open("some.txt", "r")
    numbers = []
    for num in file:
        print(num.split(A customer has purchased your))

read_file()
```

Comment: Your criteria are unclear. What are the conditions for which digits to include from the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
import re

expression = r"(?i)(?:\dollars\D{0,20})([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,]|([0-9][0-9,]*)[^.,](?:\D{0,20}dollars)"

string = "A customer has purchased your 33%-off item for 2,999 dollars"
lo=(re.findall(expression, string))
print(''.join(''.join(tup) for tup in lo))
```

output

```
2,999
```